# executing a command over ssh, and then running bash

Tags: bash, ssh, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to set up a script that opens a terminal, does an ssh to a remote server, and executes a command (tail -F logfile in my case).

What I have so far is the following

```
gnome-terminal -e 'ssh -t server "tail -F logfile"'
```

This works to some extent. -t ensures that signals like SIGINT are sent through the commands running remotely.

However, when I ctrl-c the tail, I would really like to drop down to a bash terminal *on the remote server*. Right now, if I ctrl-c the tail, then the tail is closed, which causes ssh to exit, which causes the whole terminal to be closed.

What I would like is for the tail to be terminated and be left with a bash shell on the remote server.

I have tried the following:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'ssh -t server "tail -F logfile; /bin/bash"'
```

but that doesn't seem to work. That is, if I run this without gnome-terminal, just ssh -t ..., then see the following:

```
some lines
from the log
^CConnection to server closed.
```

But, If I do

```
gnome-terminal -e 'ssh -t server "nonexistantcommand; /bin/bash"'
```

Then I get an error that nonexistantcommand is not found, and then I *do* drop down to a bash on a remote server...

Does anyone have any suggestions or hints on how to get this going? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, have a nasty hack:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'ssh -t server "echo \"tail -F logfile;rm /tmp/foo\" > /tmp/foo; bash --rcfile /tmp/foo"'
```

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks :) chx has more of an explanation in his answer as to why

Answer (score 1):

```
--init-file filename
--rcfile filename
```

> Execute commands from filename (instead of `~/.bashrc') in an interactive shell.

so run bash with --rcfile pointing to a script running tail -F.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do the obvious?  "If you got a SIGINT, execute an interactive shell."

```
gnome-terminal -e 'ssh -t server "trap \"exec sh -i\" INT; tail -F logfile"'
```